# How to call any controller function (controller may be dynamic) from a custom directive in angular 1?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I have created a common custom directive which is used for delete functionality in all the screens,so after deleting elements I need to call a controller function  to update view.controller is different based on view.

```
angular.module('app.comon').directive('deletePopup', function modal(setterGetterService,restCallService) {
        return {

            template:'<div class="modal" id="delete-popup">' +
                       '<div class="modal-dialog">' +
                         '<div class="modal-content">' +
                           '<p>Are you sure want to delete ?</p>' +
                           '<div class="buttons-group text-center">' +
                             '<a ng-click="deleteList();" class="btn">delete</a> ' +
                             '<a ng-click="cancelAction()" class="btn btn-cancel">cancel</a> ' +
                           '</div>' +
                         '</div>' +
                       '</div>' +
                     '</div>',

            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.cancelAction = function () {
                    $('#delete-popup').hide();
                }

                var dropper;

                scope.$on("DELETE_LIST", function(event, item){
                    dropper = item;
                 });

                 scope.deleteList = function () {

                    var deleteInfo =setterGetterService.getDeletePopupInfo();
    var headers =deleteInfo.headers;
                    var params = {
                        "URL" :deleteInfo.restCall ,
                        "METHOD" : deleteInfo.method,
                    }

                    restCallService.getResponse( headers, params)
                      .then(function(data) {
                        if (data.status == "success") {
                          alert("groupDeleted");     
                          $('#delete-popup').hide();         
                        } else {
                           alert(data.msg);
                        }

                     });

                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking is not the correct way to talk to other controllers.
What you should actually do is as simple as emiting an event that will notify the other controller about a situation that requires some action to be executed.

Comment: Yes  you are right, thanks for your suggestion Marcin Malinowski ..).